# PHP $mysqli->prepare error with strange syntax when table name is "check"

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

this call fails with error :

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO check VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

error i get :

> Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check VALUES
>   (?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1'

1. I have a table named "check" with right amount of fields
2. if i change table name to `checkSomething` it works ...

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You need to either surround it in backticks like this:

```
$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `check` VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Or much better, rename it to something that you don't need to constantly have a special case for.

```
$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO checks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Answer (score 3):

`check` is a reserved keyword. To use it as table name, you have to escape it with backticks like this: `` `check` `` :

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `check` VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```